# Updating Inventory

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am working on a spreadsheet that tracks inventory.  Basically each week the user goes in, sets his inventory to be used that week, compares it to the current stock and tells him when to order more.

The issue I am having is once the inventory for the week has been chosen how can I get it to update the stock permanently when he exits the spreadsheet?

Specifically then user picks the client name from a drop down menu, that in turn uses a VLOOKUP to show the items the customer needs.  From there it COUNTIFs what is needed by all customers and posts it next to the # of each item on hand(refrenced from the "stock" sheet)...I am hunky dory to this step.  I can't seem to make the leap to having the amount in stock update upon completion so that when the next user opens the file (multiple copies cannot be opened at once, already set that up) the sotck is current.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your probably going to need to use VBA.

Cant really give you any examples because I cant see the layout of your workbook and it would depend on how you want to update the list.

You could update the stock count, fairly simple to do but not very safe unless you trust all the users to get it right every time.

If you wanted a little more safety, you could have a sort of "transaction" sheet which stores the change to the stock count for each job entered. Allowing you to fix or remove any erroneous entries. This wouldn't update the main stock list so you would want to periodically merge your transaction sheet.

**Update**

I've had a quick go at making something using VBA. Again, since I don't know how your book is laid out etc I've just played about. It might be helpful, might not.

[Example Workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10316127/Adjust_Stock.xlsm)

The workbook has 3 sheets: Stock, Adjustment, Log.

**Stock**

A list of products, the quantity on hand and a re-order threshold

**Adjustment**

Used to 'adjust' the stock... user enters a product name and the requirement.
The worksheet shows the SOH, the adjusted SOH and advises weather a product needs to be reorderd. (depends on the adjusted SOH and threshold set on the stock sheet)

If the adjustment sheet is populated, when a user saves the workbook they are asked to either update the list (which clears the adjustment sheet), not to update the list (saves the adjustment list for later use without updating stock) or to cancel.

If the adjustments are saved, the information for each adjustment is copied to the log sheet along with a timestamp to allow you to track the changes. If an non-stocked (or mistyped) product is found, it is skipped and the user is told at the end.

Answer (score 0):

OK for a VBA free (sort of) solution you could use a macro. You have in 1 column the current stock, next to it it you have the amount to be deducted from it before exiting the workbook. You will need to add another column that is the amount after deduction. I'm guessing you would know how to set that up if you are using VLOOKUP.

Next step is to record the macro. I'm not sure which version of Excel you are using, but for Excel 2003 you would go to Tools -> Macro -> Record new macro. This will lead to the macro dialog box, chose a name e.g. Update. It would probably be best to  chose a shortcut key e.g. u. click OK to start recording the macro.

Highlight the column with the amount after deduction and use edit -> copy. Highlight the column with the current stock and use edit->paste special and chose values and click ok. Finally click on the stop button on the macro recorder.

If you make a mistake, simply click on stop, and go to Tools -> Macro -> Macros select the macro you have recorded and click delete and then yes. Then start again.

In order to run the macro the user would have to either goto Tools -> Macro -> Macros and click run or press Ctrl + shortcut key e.g. Ctrl+u.

A word of warning, macros are not normally undoable so if the user makes a mistake e.g. running it twice they should exit without saving and start again.